# Unable to print the absolute value for i64 type without using the variable in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to implement the method named `abs()`. When I use a variable leveraging `let`, everything works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let x = -5i64;

    println!("x == {}", x.abs());
}
```

It produces the correct output:

```
x == 5
```

But when I want to implement this without any `let` statement:

```
fn main() {
    println!("x's abs == {}", -5i64.abs());
}
```

I get the following output::

```
x's abs == -5
```

Expected output:

```
x's abs == 5
```

What is the logic behind this and how can I achieve the absolute value of literals without using variables?

## Update

I put the complete literal inside braces and then specified the type for the `abs` call:

```
fn main() {
    println!("x's abs == {}", (-5i64).abs());
}
```

It works!

But I still do not understand why would the straightforward mention:`-5i64` won't work.

Comment: Try to use parentheses around -5i64 like `(-5i64).abs()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because method calls have higher [precedence](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#expression-precedence) than `-`.
`-5i64.abs()` parses as `take absolute value of 5, then negate it`.